# Rewriting with modrewrite if file exists for clean urls

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In order to have nice clean urls with some kind of site archetecture I am using modrewrite in my .htaccess file. I don't want file extensions (.php or .html).

I have the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ $1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ $1/$2.html [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ $1/$2/$3.html [L]
```

But I want it to check if an index.html file exists in the sub-directory first.
For example, I want

```
http://example.com/first/
```

to rewrite to

```
http://example.com/first.html
```

but if that does not exist then rewrite to

```
http://example.com/first/index.html
```

The same for sub-directies, for example I want

```
http://example.com/first/second/
```

to rewrite to

```
http://example.com/first/second.html
```

but if that does not exist then rewrite to

```
http://example.com/first/second/index.html
```

Is this possible, and how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you (works for me):

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Do not do anything for already existing files and folders
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule .+ - [L]

    # add .html file extension (if such file does exist)
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/?$ $1.html [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

1. If you are using `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` then place ALL rewrite rule into between the tags, not just `RewriteEngine On`.
2. The rule checks if such file with .html extension does exist before rewriting. For `http://example.com/first/second/` it will check if `WEBSITE_ROOT/first/second.html` does exist. If not -- the will leave as is, and Apache will **automatically** pick up `http://example.com/first/second/index.html` because of `DirectoryIndex index.html` directive (see the very first line).
3. Please note: these 2 URLs are treated as the same from rewrite engine point of view: `http://example.com/first/second/` and `http://example.com/first/second` (notice that there is no trailing slash). If you want this to be 2 different URLs (only rewrite one with trailing slash) then remove `?` and `[^/]` from last rewrite rule (e.g. `RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L,QSA]`).
4. For URL `http://example.com/first/second/` -- if you have both folder `/first/second/` and file `/first/second.html` present, then request will go to a folder (and `/first/second/index.html` will be the final URL -- see #2).

Comment: Wow, thanks! That's a fantastic solution and it works even better than I thought. I already have a line that redirects to the url with the trailing slash. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RewriteCond something -f` to check if something is actually a file. For directories, you can use the -d flag instead.